# Backup Dota 2 Workshop DLC

Tags: technical-issues, dota-2

I want to share the Dota 2 Workshop DLC (5.7 GB, not the alpha) files with another PC, but the "Backup and Restore" functionality does not give that option.

I know for a fact that all the files are included in the dota_ugc folder. I also tried copying that but it was to no avail.

Is there a way to transfer the workshop tool to another laptop in order to avoid downloading the entire 5.7 GB again? Thanks in advance.